# How to modify yaml file easily using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, yaml

I have to make an editor (web-based) to modify or add new sub-items to the YAML file.it should be generic because have to use this for any yaml file.
suggest me a solution for this or mention some npm modules which might helpful

Comment: Short answer: get an YAML parser. Easily found on google. Googling for "yalm js" got me https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml and https://github.com/tj/js-yaml.